# justify content space between not working in dompdf

Tags: php, html, laravel, dompdf

I have such a report that generated by DOMPDF and created with Laravel. I want to display text, one in text-align: left, and another one in text-align: right (both in a same line). But it's not working in my code.

```
<div class="container m-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="m-0" style="font-size:.8rem;">
                            <span class="font-weight-bold">Hari, tanggal:</span> 
                            Kamis, 14 Oktober 2021
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <p class="m-0" style="font-size:.8rem;">Pagi / Siang / Malam</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Anybody would to help me with this issue please? I've been looking for this but still couldn't find the solution. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your table width.

You can do like:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container m-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
            <table class="w-100">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Hari, tanggal:</span> 
                            Kamis, 14 Oktober 2021
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        Pagi / Siang / Malam
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```